# Let $U , W\subseteq V$ be subspaces such that $\dim(U)\geq\dim(W)$. Prove that there exists a $\tau\in\text{End}(V)$ such that $\tau(U)=W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I started by taking a basis for $W$ and a basis for $U$ and extending the basis for $U$ to a basis of $V$.
Then I defined $\tau\in\text{End}(V)$ by $$\tau(a_1u_1+\cdots+a_mu_m+a_{m+1}v_{m+1}+\cdots+a_kv_k)=a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n.$$ How do I proceed?

Comment: Your formula is not entirely clear(consider clarifying), but if you mean what I think you mean, you are done. To prove that t(U)=V, just prove both inclusions.

Comment: I’m guessing that V is assumed to be finite dimensional?

Comment: You seem to be assuming $V$ (hence, also $U$) is finite-dimensional. This assumption is unnecessary, but you have to make some changes in the layout of the proof if you want it to work in the more general setting.

Comment: What changes? I took a basis for W (w_1,....w_n) and a basis for U (u_1,...u_m) which I extended to a basis of V (u_1,...,u_m,v_m+1,...,v_k. The n Imap that I defined the map above. Is it false?

Comment: If a comment is intended for me, Nick, you have to put @Gerry in it to ensure that I see it and that I know it's in response to something I wrote. When you take $w_1,\dotsc,w_n$ to be a basis for $W$, you are silently assuming $W$ is finite-dimensional. The thing you are trying to prove is true even if the spaces are not finite-dimensional. If you want a proof that works in both the finite-dimensional and the infinite-dimensional cases, you can't start out by assuming that the spaces are finite-dimensional, as you have done. So, some changes are needed.

Comment: I've left you a comment, Nick, and another user has written an answer. It's not polite to ignore people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Let  $\dim(W)=p$, $\dim(U)=m$, and $\dim(V)=n$ be the dimensions of $W$, $U$, and $V$. Since $\dim(U)\geq\dim(W)$, let $w_1,\ldots,w_p$ be a basis of $W$ and $u_1,\ldots,u_p,u_{p+1},\ldots u_m$ be a basis of $U$. By basis extension, the list $u_1,\ldots,u_p,u_{p+1},\ldots u_m,v_{m+1},\ldots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$.

Now, define the linear map $\tau:V\to V$ as
$$\tau(a_1u_1+\cdots+a_pu_p+a_{p+1}u_{p+1}+\cdots+a_mu_m+a_{m+1}v_{m+1}+\cdots+a_nv_n)=a_1w_1+\cdots+a_pw_p.$$
This map satisfies $\tau(U)=W$. Indeed, let $w=b_1w_1+\cdots+b_pw_p\in W$ be arbitrary. Choose $u=b_1u_1+\cdots+b_pu_p+0u_{p+1}+\cdots+0u_m\in U$. Then we have
$$\tau(u)=\tau(b_1u_1+\cdots+b_pu_p+0u_{p+1}+\cdots+0u_m)=b_1w_1+\cdots+b_pw_p=w.$$

Comment: You are assuming the spaces are finite-dimensional, an assumption not supported by anything in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, I have assumed that the spaces are finite-dimensional because the way the @Nick123 attempted to solve the problem and because many linear algebra books treat only finite-dimensional vector spaces. Moreover, judging by the votes up, perhaps my answer is useful for somebody.

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield Can I just map a portion of the basis vectors of $U$ to the basis vectors of $W$, and then map the excess vectors to zero, and does this hold in infinite dimensional space$V$?

Comment: @Zhiwei This is an idea worthy of consideration, but how can you rigorously prove that this idea works? I don't know.